# Type coercion of blank nodes in JSON-LD

Tags: json-ld

I have a set of JSON files that I am trying to upgrade to JSON-LD through the addition of a context reference.  One feature of the files is an array of items that are all of the same type.  I am trying to use type coercion to specify the type, but I'm having trouble.  The items in the array are represented as blank nodes, so they don't have explicit IDs - is it possible to automatically assign them types? I'm not sure if what I would like to do is possible within the JSON-LD syntax - but I'm sure you must know!

Here's what presently works:

```json
{
  "@context": 
  {
    "ex": "http://example.com/schema#",
    "items": { "@id": "ex:hasItem", "@container": "@set" },
    "item": "ex:item",
    "size": "ex:size",
    "weight": "ex:weight"
  },
  "@id": "My Item Set",
  "items": [
    {
      "@type": "item", 
      "size": 43,
      "weight": 57
    },
    {
      "@type": "item", 
      "size": 99,
      "weight": 3.14
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's what I'd like to do, but it does not have the desired effect:

```json
{
  "@context": 
  {
    "ex": "http://example.com/schema#",
    "items": { "@id": "ex:hasItem", "@container": "@set", "@type": "ex:item" },
    "size": "ex:size",
    "weight": "ex:weight"
  },
  "@id": "My Item Set",
  "items": [
    {
      "size": 43,
      "weight": 57
    },
    {
      "size": 99,
      "weight": 3.14
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there another way for me to specify that all the things in the `items` container have `@type: "item"`?